# How can I fix this JS to jQuery conversion? (re: checkbox and dropdown option selection)

Tags: javascript, jquery

For practice, I'm taking working JavaScript code and converting what I can to jQuery. I've gone through StackOverflow and the jQuery documentation and am not finding what I need. Here's my original/working JS snippet:

```
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        let prefixmenu = document.getElementById('prefix_menu');
        let prefix = prefixmenu.options[prefixmenu.selectedIndex].text;
        para.textContent = prefix + " " + output;
    } else {
        para.textContent = output;
    }
```

Without overloading you with the rest of the code, the goal is to take two form inputs, and an optional prefix (selected from a dropdown menu if a checkbox is checked), and generate those with pre-fabricated text in a 'clickbait headline generator.'

I've searched through this site and the jQuery documentation and have found things I thought might work but haven't. I tried this but then nothing prints:

```
if $("#checkbox :checked")
```

I thought this solution would work based on my research:

```
    if ($checkbox.checked) {
        let $prefix = $("#prefixmenu option:selected").text();
        $para.text($prefix + " " + output);
    } else {
        $para.text(output);
    }
})
```

From that, I get the pre-fab text with the form inputs to print, but not the prefix. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```html
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Generator inputs</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="prefix-select" name="optional_prefix">
                <label for="prefix">Select to include a prefix</label><br>
                <label for="prefix_menu">Prefix Selection:</label>
                <select id="prefix_menu">
                    <option value="1">BOOM!</option>
                    <option value="2">WOW!</option>
                    <option value="3">EPIC!</option>
                </select>
                <label for="yourname">Your name</label>
                <input type="text" id="yourname">
                <label for="othername">Another person's name</label>
                <input type="text" id="othername">
                <button type="button" id="genButton">Generate!</button>
            </fieldset>
```

Comment: It might help to include the relevant HTML to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You have three variables that you haven't declared, `$checkbox`, `$para` and `output`; where are they defined? What are they?

Comment: @DavidThomas Based on what you and showdev said, it seems I took the instructions on 'minimal reproducible example' a bit too far. I figured if I posted much more than that it would be extraneous information. Seems I was wrong particularly regarding the variables. I'll leave it at that for now since the issue has been solved.

Comment: Incidentally, I think a great summary for creating a minimal reproducible example is: "Use as little code as possible ...  Provide all parts someone else needs ... make sure it reproduces the problem" ([How to create a "reprex"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is that you're selecting `$("#prefixmenu")`, but the element's ID is "prefix_menu" (with an underscore). Use `$("#prefix_menu")` to access that element.

Also, [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) is a property of the DOM element. `$('#checkbox')` is a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/), which doesn't have a `checked` property of its own. However, you can access the DOM properties of selected elements with jQuery's [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method:

```
$checkbox.prop('checked')
```

Or you can access the property of the [first DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) directly:

```
$checkbox[0].checked
```

Or you can test against the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) CSS pseudo-class using jQuery's [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$checkbox.is(':checked')
```

Here's a working demonstration:

```js
let $checkbox = $('#checkbox');
let $prefixMenu = $("#prefix_menu");
let $genButton = $("#genButton");

$genButton.on('click', function() {
  let output = 'output';
  if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
    let prefix = $("option:selected", $prefixMenu).text();
    output = prefix + " " + output;
  }
  console.log(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Generator inputs</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="prefix-select" name="optional_prefix">
  <label for="prefix">Select to include a prefix</label><br>
  <label for="prefix_menu">Prefix Selection:</label>
  <select id="prefix_menu">
    <option value="1">BOOM!</option>
    <option value="2">WOW!</option>
    <option value="3">EPIC!</option>
  </select>
  <label for="yourname">Your name</label>
  <input type="text" id="yourname">
  <label for="othername">Another person's name</label>
  <input type="text" id="othername">
  <button type="button" id="genButton">Generate!</button>
</fieldset>
```

These examples from [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) further help to visualize those concepts:

```
if ( elem.checked )
if ( $( elem ).prop( "checked" ) )
if ( $( elem ).is( ":checked" ) )
```

### Edit

I might use [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to define the values:

```js
let $checkbox = $('#checkbox');
let $prefixMenu = $("#prefix_menu");
let $genButton = $("#genButton");
let output = 'Output';

$genButton.on('click', function() {

  let prefix = $checkbox.is(':checked')
    ? $("option:selected", $prefixMenu).text()
    : false;

  let headline = prefix
    ? prefix + " " + output
    : output;

  console.log(headline);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Generator inputs</legend>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="prefix-select" name="optional_prefix">
  <label for="prefix">Select to include a prefix</label><br>
  <label for="prefix_menu">Prefix Selection:</label>
  <select id="prefix_menu">
    <option value="1">BOOM!</option>
    <option value="2">WOW!</option>
    <option value="3">EPIC!</option>
  </select>
  <label for="yourname">Your name</label>
  <input type="text" id="yourname">
  <label for="othername">Another person's name</label>
  <input type="text" id="othername">
  <button type="button" id="genButton">Generate!</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I refactored based on your answer and it worked. As to the ternary operators (and everything, really), I still have a lot to learn. Thank you!